# Dual of k-algebra is the opposite algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, bimodules, bicategories

I am dealing with monoidal bicategory which has algebras, bimodules and bimodule maps as objects, 1-morphisms and 2-morphisms respectively.

Let $k$ be a commutative ring. We take any $k$-algebra $A$ and **claim** that its dual is the algebra $A^{op}$. The algebra morphisms are taken in the form of bimodules. In particular, $id_A = {}_AA_A$, $id_{A^{op}} = {}_{A^{op}}A_{A^{op}}$, $ev_A = {}_{A \otimes_k A^{op}}A_k$ and $coev_A = {}_k A_{A^{op} \otimes_k A}$. Composition of bimdolues is given by $\otimes_?$ where "?" denotes intermediate algebra.  My attempt is:

$$(ev_A \otimes_k id_A) \otimes_? (id_A \otimes_k coev_A)$$ $$= (ev_A \otimes_? id_A) \otimes_k (id_A \otimes_? coev_A)$$ $$= ({}_{A \otimes_k A^{op}}A_k \otimes_? {}_AA_A) \otimes_k ({}_AA_A \otimes_? {}_kA_{A^{op} \otimes_k A})$$  $$= ({}_AA_A \otimes_? {}_AA_A) \otimes_k ({}_AA_A \otimes_? {}_AA_A)$$  $$= ( {}_AA_A) \otimes_k ({}_AA_A)$$ $$= {}_AA_A$$

where in the 2nd line I use $(f \otimes g) \circ (f' \otimes g') = (f \circ f') \otimes (g \circ g')$, in the 4th line I substitute both of ${}_{A \otimes_k A^{op}}A_k$ and ${}_kA_{A^{op} \otimes_k A}$ with ${}_AA_A$ following [this equality and isomorphism respectively](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781850/defining-the-enveloping-algebra) (*can I just do this? why? clearly its important what we view the bimodule as, since the two sides represent the source and target object*), and in the 5th line I used the fact that $ {}_AA_A$ is the identity in terms of composition $\otimes_?$ for A-bimodule, and in the last line I used that monoidal tensor of the two objects which are the same will give the same object

> which is confusing as I was looking at it as a bimodule until now which is the 1-morphism, and in this step as the algebra which is the 0-morphism/object; although it would make sense because the tensor of same 1-morphisms will act on the tensor of same source objects which in turn give just the same source object automatically thus we just get the same 1-morphism. That is, monoidal tensor of two same 1-morphisms is the same 1-morphism (?)

Is this correct so far? If so, does this successfully  prove the [zigzag equation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/triangle+identities) and thus the **claim**?

I feel I would be more comfortable dealing with algebra morphisms directly than bimodules, although what would the $ev_A, coev_A$  maps be explicitly then as just morphisms? Or more generally, **what would be the "recipe" for converting between an explicit morphism and the associated bimodule (and vice versa)?** The particular case presented here would be a nice expository example for me.

Comment: been some time since I did these things explicitly, but all looks perfect. if I understand correctly you implicitly already assume that all your modules are actually functors between $\mathbb{k}$-linear categories? as that might make some of your computations clearer and would explain you calling it the composition of bimodules.

Comment: @Enkidu I have edited to clarify. The modules here have replaced the algebra morphism, and although I read that there is a 2-functor from category of algebras and morphisms to this bicategory, which maps the morphisms from algebras A to B to  corresponding A-B-bimodules, I don't quite understand how it goes about explicitly. Hence the last paragraph is my main question.